# Eclipse can't resolve MidiSystem.getSequencer()

Tags: java, eclipse, javax.sound.midi

Eclipse is throwing the **error :**

```
"MidiSystem.getSequencer cannot be resolved to a type"
```

I am running `JavaSE- 1.7 with compliance level 1.7`

Not sure what is going on here

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
public class drumKit{

    public void play(){
        try{
            Sequencer sequencer = new MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            System.out.println("got it");
        }
        catch(MidiUnavailableException ex){
            System.out.println("Cannot find");
        }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        drumKit d = new drumKit();
        d.play();
   }
}
```

Comment: remove `new` from your statement. It's a `static` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getSequencer() is a static method , no need to use the `new` keyword

```
public void play(){
    try{
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        System.out.println("got it");
    }
```